# How can I change listbox item's visibility property in wp7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

For example:
there is a listbox:

```
<ListBox Margin="24,107,12,28" Name="lb">
  <TextBlock Text="Text" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="22" Visibility="Collapsed" />
  <TextBlock Text="Text2" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="22" Visibility="Collapsed" />
  <TextBlock Text="Text3" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="22" Visibility="Collapsed" />
</ListBox>
```

How can I change TextBlocks's visibility properties programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ListBox`generates a container of type `ListBoxItem` for each item. You can access it as follows:

```
ListBoxItem lbi = lb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ListBoxItem
lbi.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

If you want access to the `TextBlock` you will need to navigate the visual tree of the `ListBoxItem`. For example, using [Linq to VisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/):

```
TextBlock txt = lbi.Descendants<TextBlock>().Single() as TextBlock;
```