# Toggle visibility of listbox with a button?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change listbox item’s visibility property in wp7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427695/how-can-i-change-listbox-items-visibility-property-in-wp7)

Could you help me toggle the visibility of a listbox with a button?

This is what I have:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    listbox1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    if (listbox1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed) ;
    {
       Visibility.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do the job though not as concise as scartag's answer , SilverLight and WPF have the Visibility property now, gone are the days of using a bool to set visibility.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (listbox1.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed) 
    {
        listbox1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible ;
    }
    else
        listbox1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   listbox1.Visibility = listbox1.Visibility == Visibility.Visible? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;        
}
```

Comment: One of the elegantest versions seen :)